# Magento - Custom REST API giving 404

Tags: rest, magento

I've followed a tutorial online on how to create a custom REST API endpoint for Magento 1.9.2. However, after completing the oauth process and getting a secret and key I always get a 404 trying to call the endpoint.

I think my problem is coming from the api.xml file as I don't quite understand the values that can be used for the various options. The file is below:

```
<config>
    <api2>
        <resource_groups>
            <categories translate="title" module="EG_Categories">
                <title>Categories API</title>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            </categories>
        </resource_groups>
        <resources>
            <categories translate="title" module="EG_Categories">
                <group>categories</group>
                <model>categories/api2_categoriesapi</model>
                <title>Category API</title>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <privileges>
                    <admin>
                        <create>1</create>
                        <retrieve>1</retrieve>
                    </admin>
            <guest>
            <retrieve>1</retrieve>
            </guest>
                </privileges>
                <attributes>
                    <name>Category Name</name>
                    <parent>Parent ID</parent>
                </attributes>
                <routes>
                    <route>
                        <route>/categories/retrieve</route>
                        <action_type>collection</action_type>
                    </route>
                </routes>
                <versions>1</versions>
            </categories>
        </resources>
    </api2>
</config>
```

In particular, I haven't been able to find out if collection is the correct value for the action type to activate the _retrieveCollection method in the class file.

I have one class file located at app/code/local/EG/Categories/Model/Api2/Categories.php.
Also in APi2 is /Categories/Rest/Admin/V1.php.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: What request URL are you using? What have you named your API classes, and what are their folder locations? **Have you cleared your cache?** Have you assigned the correct API ACLs and attribute permissions for this resource?

Comment: The request URL is api/rest/categories/retrieve. Cache is turned off. The API classes I have added above.